# Powershell - Delete folders containing a file with a specific FileDescription?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am using the below code to get the FileDescription of a file:

```
(dir C:\test.exe).VersionInfo | select-object FileDescription | fl
```

This is working fine, the next step is: I am looking to search for all files that end with a specific FileDescription, then delete the folders where these files reside. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: `(dir C:\test.exe).VersionInfo | Where-Object{$_.FileDescription -like "*endofdescription"} | Remove-Item -WhatIf`. Guessing would have some sort of ForEach-Object loop with output from a `Get-ChildItem` call

Comment: Thanks! I am having trouble with the Remove-item part, getting "Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'File' does not exist."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in my pipe. The file information was lost since we only pipe `.VersionInfo`

```
Get-ChildItem C:\test.exe | Where-Object{$_.VersionInfo.FileDescription -like "*endofdescription"} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

It would make more sense if you were to use `-Recurse` to return more file and keep using `Where-Object` to filter just the ones you want. This should find the files and return their folder names. Since there could be more than one file in a folder that matches we could pipe the results in `Select-Object -Unique` to get the individual folders.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\MyFolder -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.VersionInfo.FileDescription -like "*endofdescription"} | ForEach-Object{Split-Path $_.FullName -Parent} | Select-Object -Unique | ForEach-Object{Remove-Item $_ -WhatIf -Confirm:$false -Force -Recurse}
```

I leave the `-WhatIf` as a precaution. Remove if the code suits your needs.

Comment: That works, but that deletes the file, not the folder where the file resides. Is there a way around that? Thanks!

Comment: @user2953714 i have updated my post for a folder based solution.

Comment: Thank you! Theres a confirmation dialog that opens, is there a way to suppress that?

Comment: `-Confirm:$false` would be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Get-ChildItem C:\MyFolder -Recurse | `
Where-Object{$_.VersionInfo.FileDescription -like "*endofdescription"} |`
%{$_.DirectoryName}|`
sort-object -unique| `
remove-item -recurse -whatif
```